# React-Route Link with react-router-dom V6

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

When I click on the button of the *secondpage*, it is added to this landing page at the very bottom(after Footer). The transition comes from the *courses* page. How do I make the *secondpage* open as a new page, and not as an addition to the landing page(after Footer)?
I mean, that it looks like:
Header
Zagolovok
Courses
Teacher
Fiq
Footer
SecondPage

But it is necessary that only:
SecondPage

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Header } from './Header';
import { Advantages } from './Advantages';
import { Zagolovok } from './Zagolovok';
import { Something } from './Something';
import { Courses } from './Courses';
import { Teachers } from './Teachers';
import { Fiq } from './Fiq';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import { SecondPage } from './SecondPage'; // Импортируйте новую страницу


function App() {
  return (
          <div className="App" style={{ color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif' }}>
              <Header />
              <Zagolovok />
              <Advantages />
              <Courses />
              <Teachers />
              <Something />
              <Fiq />
              <Footer />
              <Routes>
                  <Route path="/courses" element={<Courses />} />
                  <Route path="/secondpage" element={<SecondPage />} />
              </Routes>
          </div>
  );
};

export default App;`
```

**In courses page:**

```
<Link to="/secondpage" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                <button className="register-button" onClick={handleRegistration}>
                  Registration
                </button>
</Link>`
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "untitled3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Recognize that your React app is a "tree of components" that begins with the root component, normally called `<App>`.

If you want to just show `<SecondPage>` when it is navigated to, then you cannot have your root element rendering all the rest of the stuff you no longer want to see.

So change `App.jsx` to something like:

```js
return (
  <div className="App" style={{ color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif' }}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/courses" element={<Courses />} />
      <Route path="/secondpage" element={<SecondPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
);
```

and move the other tags into `<Courses>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `App` component is unconditionally rendering the header, footer, and everything between, all above the routes you are navigating to.

Refactor the code to render the main content on a route as well. Move the routes between the header and footer.

Example:

```
const Home = () => (
  <>
    <Zagolovok />
    <Advantages />
    <Courses />
    <Teachers />
    <Something />
    <Fiq />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif' }}>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/courses" element={<Courses />} />
        <Route path="/secondpage" element={<SecondPage />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you like, you can also create a layout route to render the header and footer.

Example:

```
import { ..., Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
    <Footer />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ color: 'white', fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif' }}>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/courses" element={<Courses />} />
          <Route path="/secondpage" element={<SecondPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```